# Variable in input's value string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a variable(Post title) to my string for my input text field's value.

I just get to see `#{@post.title}` though, instead of the true title.

What am I doing wrong?

In my form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :value => 'Enquiry about post #{@post.title}' %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right quotes, you need to use double quotes `"` for string interpolation:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :value => "Enquiry about post #{@post.title}" %>
```

Please find some further information on [`Interpolation`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) at wikibooks.